# Xcode 7.1.1 - fatal error : lipo: can't open input file

Tags: build-error, ios9.1, lipo, xcode7.1.1

I'm getting `fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/.../libABC.a (No such file or directory)`

[image: Screenshot 1]

I've cross-checked this file exists in same location after checking with `'Show in Finder'`

I'm getting this error while *building library*. I've tried below solutions but didn't worked:

```
1. Build Active architecture only - YES/NO
2. Enable BitCode - YES/NO
3. Clean / Clean Build Folder, Quit simulator.
```

Any other fix?

Comment: What does ' ls -l libABC* ' say? Have you tried a clean and then build?

Comment: @kometen : read question properly.

Comment: The ls-command will show you if the file has the correct permissions so an unprivileged user can read it. And is located where you expect to find it.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.Did you find any solution to fix this?  Please help

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode-Build phases**

**check the scripts wheacher contain codes or not look like this to Removex86_64Andi386Framework:**

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

**delete the shell script and clean the project then run again.**